# Systemd.path: Combine multiple conditions with a logical OR

Tags: systemd

In the manual of `systemd.path`, it is said that the "conditions" can be combined, however it is not said how.

I guess it is a logical "and", and if you want to do a logical "or" you should use multiple `path` triggering the same target. Am I right?

Edit: As an example, I have a *A.path* triggered for a certain amount of time by a timer, it triggers *A.service* that empty a *queue* folder.

- If *queue* is not empty when *A.path* is triggered, I want *A.service* to start; `DirectoryNotEmpty` do this.
- If file are added to *queue* during the functionning period, I also want it to start; `PathModified` monitors files added/removed, but only during the functioning period and won't trigger the service if the files have been added outside of the functioning period.

So in the end, I want it to run if the *queue* directory is not empty when started, or if the content of *queue* is modified during the functioning period.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a vertical pipe before each condition that stands alone.

From the [freedesktop manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html):

> If multiple conditions are specified, the unit will be executed if all
>   of them apply (i.e. a logical AND is applied). Condition checks can be
>   prefixed with a pipe symbol (|) in which case a condition becomes a
>   triggering condition. If at least one triggering condition is defined
>   for a unit, then the unit will be executed if at least one of the
>   triggering conditions apply and all of the non-triggering conditions.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough, I did not mean conditions but the `[Path]` options like `DirectorNotEmpty`.

Comment: I have added an example to give some context.